# Add items to ConcurrentBag used to Parallel.ForEach c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to crawl several URLs concurrently. Each request may add more URLs to the `ConcurrentBag` for crawling. At the moment I've got a nasty while(true) that starts a new `Parallel.ForEach` to process any new URLs.

Is there any way I can add to the contents of the `ConcurrentBag` so the `Parallel.ForEach` will see there are new items in it and continue iterating through these new items?

```
ConcurrentBag<LinkObject> URLSToCheck = new ConcurrentBag<LinkObject>();

while (true)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(URLSToCheck, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, URL =>
    {
        Checker Checker = new Checker();

        URLDownloadResult result = Checker.downloadFullURL(URL.destinationURL);

        List<LinkObject> URLsToAdd = Checker.findInternalUrls(URL.sourceURL, result.html);

        foreach (var URLToAdd in URLsToAdd)
        {
            URLSToCheck.Add(new LinkObject { sourceURL = URLToAdd.sourceURL, destinationURL = URLToAdd.destinationURL });
        }
    });

    if(URLSToCheck.Count == 0)break;
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to dive into recursive code. This is a typical example of where it applies. Btw, beware of circular references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataFlow can be handy here. With [`ActionBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) it can be done nicely:

```
// Capture the variable, so it can be used in the next block
ActionBlock<LinkObject> = actionBlock = null;

actionBlock = new ActionBlock<LinkObject>(URL =>
{
    Checker Checker = new Checker();
    URLDownloadResult result = Checker.downloadFullURL(URL.destinationURL);
    List<LinkObject> URLsToAdd = Checker.findInternalUrls(URL.sourceURL, result.html);
    URLsToAdd.ForEach(actionBlock.Post)
},new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5});
```

And then add to the `actionBlock` your initial urls:

```
actionBlock.Post(url1);
actionBlock.Post(url2);
...
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped :-) If anyone else uses this install Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow through NuGet

Answer (score 5):

You can take a look at [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx).

The BlockingCollection provides an implementation of the producer/consumer pattern: your producer will add to the blocking collection and your Parallel.ForEach will consume from the collection.

To do so you will have to implement a custom partitioner for the BlockingCollection (the reason is explained here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/06/parallelextensionsextras-tour-4-blockingcollectionextensions/)

Partitioner:

```
class BlockingCollectionPartitioner<T> : Partitioner<T>
{
    private BlockingCollection<T> _collection;

    internal BlockingCollectionPartitioner(BlockingCollection<T> collection)
    {
        if (collection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
        _collection = collection;
    }

    public override bool SupportsDynamicPartitions 
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override IList<IEnumerator<T>> GetPartitions(int partitionCount)
    {
        if (partitionCount < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("partitionCount");

        var dynamicPartitioner = GetDynamicPartitions();
        return Enumerable.Range(0, partitionCount).Select(_ => dynamicPartitioner.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
    }

    public override IEnumerable<T> GetDynamicPartitions()
    {
        return _collection.GetConsumingEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Then you will use it like:

```
BlockingCollection<LinkObject> URLSToCheck = new BlockingCollection<LinkObject>();

Parallel.ForEach(
    new BlockingCollectionPartitioner<LinkObject>(URLSToCheck), 
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, URL =>
       {
            //....
       });
```

in another thread you will add to the URLSToCheck collection:

```
URLSToCheck.Add(...)
```

when you finish the urls to process, you call `URLSToCheck.CompleteAdding()`
and the `Parallel.ForEach` should automatically stop.